# i am using R in Docker . But having error in running libraries

Tags: r, docker, gdal, r-package

I am using R in docker . I have install libraries in docker by using docker hub.but failed . Below is the error i am facing

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘geojsonio’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgeos/libs/rgeos.so':
  libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `libgeos_c.so.1` is provided in an OS-level package, not an R-level package. Since it says it cannot find that library, it sounds like `libgeos-dev` (or similar) needs to be installed. If that `.deb` is not installed, there's nothing you can do in R to remedy that error.

Comment: taha yab, what docker image are you using or basing off of? If you're using any of the [`rocker`](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker)-based images, then I believe they are all debian (or ubuntu) based, in which case Jared's answer should work (after you also `apt-get update` within the container during the build stage).

Comment: @r2evans Yes, of course. I misread the library’s filename as being the one from the package.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I had to look, to be honest, and verified that I only saw `rgeos.so`. It's an easy mistake to make, and a troubleshooting step that I believe few new-to-R users will know to check. (You, of course, are not new-to-R, but with so many questions on SO about *"package doesn't install"*, it's an easy one to make :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That package has a lot of Linux library dependencies which probably aren't in the image. You can install them by adding these install commands to your Dockerfile.

```
apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libssl-dev \
libjq-dev \
libprotobuf-dev \
protobuf-compiler \
make \
libgeos-dev \
libudunits2-dev \
libgdal-dev \
gdal-bin \
libproj-dev \
libv8-dev
```

You can find that information at https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/2/packages/geojsonio